# Can't find the right return type for a linq query output

Tags: c#, linq, asp.net-web-api

I have the following method that returns the output of the LINQ query. The method works perfectly fine but I have dynamic as a return type because the following 2 didn't work: List & IEnumerable. What should be the correct return type be for a LINQ query output? My method:

```
public dynamic GetUserFollowers(Guid user_gd)
{
   var listOfFollowers = from users in _context.Users
                         from userFollowing in _context.UserFollowings.Where(
                            uf => uf.User2 != users.Gd && uf.User2 == user_gd && uf.User1 == users.Gd
                         )
                         select new { users.Gd, users.Firstname, users.Lastname, users.Username, users.Email };

   return listOfFollowers;
}
```

User model:

```
public class User
{
    [Key]
    public Guid Gd { get; set; }

    public string Firstname { get; set; }

    public string Lastname { get; set; }

    public string Username { get; set; }

    public string Email { get; set; }

    public byte[] PasswordHash { get; set; }

    public byte[] PasswordSalt { get; set; }
}
```

Error when using List< User >:

> Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.Linq.IQueryable<<anonymous
> type: System.Guid Gd, string Firstname, string Lastname, string
> Username, string Email>>' to
> 'System.Collections.Generic.List<CosialAPI.Authorization.Entities.User>'.
> An explicit conversion exists (are you missing a cast?)

Error when using IEnumerable< User >:

> Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.Linq.IQueryable<<anonymous
> type: System.Guid Gd, string Firstname, string Lastname, string
> Username, string Email>>' to
> 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<CosialAPI.Authorization.Entities.User>'.
> An explicit conversion exists (are you missing a cast?)

Help would be appreciated!

Comment: why don;t you use dictionaries? not sure just a question...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Return value for the current code is in the error message:

```
IQueryable<<anonymous type: System.Guid Gd, string Firstname, string Lastname, string Username, string Email>>
```

Change this line

```
select new { users.Gd, users.Firstname, users.Lastname, users.Username, users.Email };
```

with this one

```
select new User() { Gd = users.Gd, Firstname = users.Firstname, Lastname = users.Lasname, Username = users.Username };
```

Then you can change `dynamic` with `IEnumerable<User>`.

If you want to change the return type to `List<User>`, add a `ToList()` as @juharr said in the comments.

Comment: They'd have to do a `ToList` to use the `List<User>` return type.

Comment: @juharr right, thank you for pointing that out, will edit the answer :)

Comment: Wow didn't think about that! Thanks for helping guys I appreciate it!

Comment: glad to be helpful :)

Answer (score 1):

Another option is to create a new class with only the properties you want to expose.
E.g.

```cs
public class UserDto
{
    public Guid Gd { get; set; }
    public string Firstname { get; set; }
    public string Lastname { get; set; }
    public string Username { get; set; }
    public string Email { get; set; }
}
```

then use it in the query

```cs
select new UserDto
{
    Gd = users.Gd,
    Firstname = users.Firstname,
    Lastname = users.Lastname,
    Username = users.Username,
    Email = users.Email
};
```

and use either `.AsEnumerable()` or `.ToList()` to get a return type of `IEnumerable<UserDto>` or `List<UserDto>`.

```cs
return listOfFollowers.ToList(); // or .AsEnumerable()
```

Comment: Yes exactly! Totally forgot about DTO's which are important. Thanks for helping I will add it to my code.